# Python Module identifies as dict

Tags: python

Lets say I have a lot of key-pair data. I would like to have this data in a package so that it can be imported. Is there a way to make modules work like dicts, for performance and extendibility reasons?

Example:

```
common/pairs/
 ├── BUILDINGS.py
 └── __init__.py

import BUILDINGS

BUILDINGS["foo"] == "bar"
```

Note: The desired result can be archived by putting declaring `BUILDINGS` in `__init__.py` but they will all be compiled every time, its not drag and undroppable, and it seems ugly.

Is there a way to achieve this well? Is there a way to achieve it at all?

Comment: Why isn't `BUILDINGS.foo` good enough?

Comment: I am curious, what do you expect to gain by importing data from a package versus loading it from an external resource ?

Comment: Compile? If you import it once, a cache `pyc` file will exist and you don't need to "recompile" to bytecode. True that if you import ``pairs`` then the dict is loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not that I recommend it, but you can assign the `dict` into `sys.modules`. Python doesn't care that what's there is actually a module object.

```
# BUILDINGS.py
from sys import modules
if __name__ != "__main__":
    modules[__name__] = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, ...}
```

Comment: Works as expected with removal of "sys." on line 4. Thanks.

Comment: Oh yeah, I originally just imported `sys` and changed that without changing the other use. Fixed. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Modules are already dicts with their atributes stored in `BUILDINGS.__dict__`. Just make an utility fonction to write directly to it.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, I think what you want is the `pickle` package

ie,

```
In [16]: import pickle

In [17]: mydict = {'this':1, 'is':2, 'my':3, 'dict':4}

In [18]: mydict
Out[18]: {'dict': 4, 'is': 2, 'my': 3, 'this': 1}

In [20]: outfile = open('/tmp/mydict.pickle', 'w')

In [21]: pickle.dump(mydict, outfile)

In [22]: outfile.close()

In [23]: infile = open('/tmp/mydict.pickle', 'r')

In [24]: mydict_loaded = pickle.load(infile)

In [25]: mydict_loaded
Out[25]: {'dict': 4, 'is': 2, 'my': 3, 'this': 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store key-value data that you want to reference later, you should try  the [shelve](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html) module

Example from the above linked page

```
import shelve

d = shelve.open(filename) # open -- file may get suffix added by low-level
                          # library

d[key] = data   # store data at key (overwrites old data if
                # using an existing key)
data = d[key]   # retrieve a COPY of data at key (raise KeyError if no
                # such key)
del d[key]      # delete data stored at key (raises KeyError
                # if no such key)
flag = d.has_key(key)   # true if the key exists
klist = d.keys() # a list of all existing keys (slow!)

# as d was opened WITHOUT writeback=True, beware:
d['xx'] = range(4)  # this works as expected, but...
d['xx'].append(5)   # *this doesn't!* -- d['xx'] is STILL range(4)!

# having opened d without writeback=True, you need to code carefully:
temp = d['xx']      # extracts the copy
temp.append(5)      # mutates the copy
d['xx'] = temp      # stores the copy right back, to persist it

# or, d=shelve.open(filename,writeback=True) would let you just code
# d['xx'].append(5) and have it work as expected, BUT it would also
# consume more memory and make the d.close() operation slower.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you *really* want a module that you can use as a `dict`, you have to make it implement the mapping protocol.

In particular, you need to make sure that `type(BUILDINGS).__getitem__(BUILDINGS, key)` is defined (as, e.g., `getattr(BUILDINGS, key)`. And likewise for `__setitem__`, `__delitem__`, and anything else you want to implement. (You can get most of what you want through `collections.abc.MutableMapping`, or `collections.MutableMapping` if you're on 2.x. See [the docs](http://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections-abstract-base-classes) for exactly what you have to implement to get everything else for free.)

The problem is that (at least in CPython, which is probably what you care about) `module` is a builtin type whose attributes cannot be modified. So, you need to cause `BUILDINGS` to be an instance of a different type, which you can then add `__getitem__` to. For example:

```
class DictModuleType(types.ModuleType, collections.abc.MutableMapping):
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return getattr(self, key)
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        return setattr(self, key, value)
    # ... etc.

import BUILDINGS as _BUILDINGS
BUILDINGS = DictModuleType('BUILDINGS')
for name, member in inspect.getmembers(_BUILDINGS):
    if not name.startswith('_'):
        setattr(BUILDINGS, name, member)
```

Now you've got a `BUILDINGS` that acts just like the real module, except that it also provides dict-like access instead of just namespace-like access.

You can wrap this up in a variety of different ways.

The simplest way is to take effectively that code (but using `__import__` or `imp` so you don't pollute `globals` and `sys.modules` with the intermediate value) and put it in a function, so instead of `import BUILDINGS` you'd write `helper_mod.dict_import(BUILDINGS)`.

The most powerful way is to create and install an [import hook](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0302/) that just returns a `DictModuleType` instead of `ModuleType` (you may need to implement `__new__` and/or `__init__` to make this work) for, say, all modules whose names are in all caps (just check if `fullname.split('.')[-1].isupper()`, and, if not, don't wrap it). Then, you can just write a module named `BUILDINGS.py`, and `import BUILDINGS`, and `BUILDINGS` will act like a `dict`.